# how to find low element from 3 dimension array

Tags: image, matlab, min, multidimensional-array

When we read color image information
we will get data in rows x cols x 3(RGB color)

I want to extract the min value from separate color

Originally I could do

```
R = I(:,:,1);
G = I(:,:,2);
B = I(:,:,3);
```

to extract separate data color and normally find min by

```
Rmin = min(R(:));
```

and so on...

but Is there any proper solution to use min?

I tried

```
min(I(:,:,1:3));
```

but it didn't right (dimension answer was 1xcolx3 : It should be 1x3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you have to use the nested min. For example use the following command

```
min(min(I, [], 1), [], 2)
```

This should give the result you want.

Comment: Yes this one is work thank you so much... So how does it work? the outer min separate the 3 data layer and inner min find the lower from the separated data is that correct?

Comment: @someone if this helps then accept the answer. This may help others

Comment: +1. Note that you can safely rely on default behavior and thus compact this to `max(max(I),[],2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
min(min(min(I,3)))
```

or for a cleaner output:

```
squeeze(min(min(min(I,3))))
```

There is probably a nicer way, without nesting the `min` function.